# Cannot use @istest in Apex Triggers

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I'm brand new to Apex/Salesforce development, and am attempting to create some Apex triggers and tests. Each time I try to add a new class, when I start it with @IsTest I am unable to save it. I see the error: "Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: @ at line 1 column 0".

Is there somewhere else I'm supposed to put tests for triggers? Or something else I should be doing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating a brand new test class or are you trying to add this directly to the trigger?

Comment: Brand new class. I have CheckLead (as one class, where the trigger is) and CheckLead_test, where line 1 is @IsTest

Comment: What IDE Are you using? What API Version?

Comment: I'm just using the Developer Console from Setup. API version seems to be 31.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I believe you have pointed me in the right direction. I spent some time installing/setting up the Force.com IDE/Eclipse, and I do not see the error there. Further, the trigger for which I was trying to write a test now says it is 100% covered. Would you want to make an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case other folks find this one, the problem was with the Developer Console (at least in our case it was). I was unable to create new test classes in there, but instead had to install Eclipse and Force.com package and deploy from there.

To be clear, I can run tests in Developer Console, but have to create them in Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Triggers can't have annotations, and while they can contain classes, those classes can't be "special" classes, such as @RestResource classes. You need to make a *class* to test the trigger. Do not confuse a class with a trigger. A trigger looks like a class, but has different semantics.

The following code won't compile:

```
@isTest trigger MyTrigger on Case (after insert) { ...
```

Nor will this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    @isTest class TestTrigger { ...
```

Instead, make your trigger:

```
trigger X on Y (...) { ...
```

And a class for that trigger:

```
@isTest class TestTriggerX {
     @isTest static void testTrigger() { ...
```

Classes are made in Setup > Develop > Apex Classes, while triggers are made on the object (e.g. Setup > Customize > Accounts > Triggers). The word "class" generally should never appear in your triggers, and the word "trigger" should generally never appear in your classes.

You can't combine multiple top-level elements into a single class or trigger.

Comment: Currently, I have CheckLead_test as an Apex Class (as you say) and CheckLead as a trigger. CheckLead_test starts like this:

`@isTest
class CheckLead_Test {
static testMethod void insertNewLead() {`

Comment: If this was possible, it would be quite a nice way to test Platform Events have been published. Because you could have a @isTest subscriber trigger class...